# Refresh DrawerLayout from a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, refresh, drawer

I have 3 classes, as follow:

```
Drawer.java:

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.action_center);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Where the drawer is implemented. I have read that I should implement

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Inside of

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    mMenuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(true);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

CustomAdapter.java:

```
    Where the custom adapter is implemented.
```

PlanetFragment.java:

```
public class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
ListView lv;

public PlanetFragment() {
    // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
}

//@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);

    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(SecondCustomAdapter...);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

   /***I want to refresh the drawer when an item on the fragment is               
    clicked, but I just can't figure out a way to do it...***/
    }
  }
}
```

Can you help me here please?

Thank you!

Comment: You can call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to invalidate the drawer and force it to be recreated if you have it's reference.

Comment: Rightnow I don't have its reference, how can I access to the reference from the fragment?

Comment: Any tip to help me here?

Comment: You could simply pass a reference to  the drawer in your `PlanetFragment` constructer and save it in a global variable to be accessed and refreshed from within the fragment.